# Flipping cards on click stopped working after creating cards dynamically with JS instead of hard-coding them in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm presenting my projects as flip-cards in my portfolio. Originally, the project data was hard-coded in my index.html, the cards flip on hover on larger screen and on click on smaller screens.

I decided to move all the hard-coded data to an object in my script.js to create a flip-card for each project in that object dynamically. No issue here. (Next to that, I also added a loading background animation to the cards, so that those are only showing their content after a few secs. Also no issue here.)

However, now that I'm creating the flip-cards to the DOM with JS, the event listener attached to the cards is not working as it used to. Logging the cards to the console does show me a full node list of all the created divs, but nothing happens when clicking the cards on smaller screens.

I feel like this is a scope issue but I'm not sure. I've tried placing the event listener function:

- inside `createProjectCard(projects)`, right after creating and appending the flip-cards: no response or error thrown, but node list does contain all the created cards
- inside `createProjectCard(projects)`, right after the `setTimeout()` function: no response or error thrown, but node list does contain all the created cards
- inside `createProjectCard(projects)` and within the `setTimeout()` function (at its bottom): here something weird happens, only the cards for which the index is an uneven number can be flipped on click; also, if I `console.log('clicked')` to test the event listener, all cards are logging 'clicked' instead of just the one I clicked.
- outside of `createProjectCard(projects)`: no response or error thrown, but node list does contain all the created cards

I'm wondering if this issue comes from nesting `innerFlipCards.forEach` inside `projects.forEach`, but I don't know how else to access the `innerFlipCards` since they are created within `projects.forEach`.

Old code with hard coded project data, but flip-cards work on mobile: https://codepen.io/awelie_go/pen/KKXPQBJ

New code with dynamic project data, but flip-cards don't work on mobile: https://codepen.io/awelie_go/pen/OJxLQvQ

If anyone has a hint on how to fix this, I would love to hear.
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is a couple of issues in the non-working code.
Due to the setTimeout inside of your loop, the cards aren't created immediately, but
`const innerFlipCards = document.querySelectorAll(".flip-card-inner");`
tries to get a list of them and loop through them, however, since there are no cards yet, the result is empty.

If however we remove the timeout, there is another issue. The same line of code mentioned above (which is followed by a loop through the results), executes on every loop iteration.
What that means is, if you have 3 cards, your first card will have 3 click event handlers, your second will have 2 and third only 1. Which explains why only odd cards worked. It would be similar to if the user clicked the 1st card 3 times quickly.

So how should we remedy this? A more straightforward fix would be to create `flip-card-inner` div with `createElement`, add your event listeners to it and append it to your `flip-card`. That way you can set everything up at creation, instead of having to query for your cards later and worry about timings.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! To address your first observation, however, this is what I don't get: the `innerFlipCards` value _is_ made accessible through the line `flipCard.innerHTML = `<div class="flip-card-inner"><div class="flip-card-front"></div>` declared before the `setTimeout()` and when I log it to the console (outside of my `projects.forEach()`), I do see an a node list full of `div.flip-card-inner`. And since my event handler on that NodeList is located outside of the `projects.forEach()`, it shouldn’t execute on each iteration of that `forEach()`, should it?

Comment: Nevertheless I did try two different approaches based on your suggestion and updated the pen with each attempt. **First attempt**: this is imo quite similar to my initial code but in a more convoluted way, as I’m creating an array of `div.flip-card-inner` (created with `createElement()`) in order to iterate over it to add the event listener (_outside_ the `projects.forEach()`). Unfortunately same results as before.

Comment: **Second attempt** (that code is commented out in the pen for clarity): After creating the `innerFlipCards` with `createElement()`, I added the event listener and appended the element to the `flipCard`. Also here no difference.

Comment: @awelie_go I'll write a more detailed answer tomorrow evening if you don't find a solution by then.

Comment: Thank you @StereoBucket, I unfortunately didn't come up with a solution today

Comment: @awelie_go, I took a look at your code. You added the innerFlipCards, but then 1.5 seconds later overwrite them with new divs through `flipCard.innerHTML`. You'll lose your event handlers.

Comment: Omg, thank you, I didn't know about this aspect of event listeners. I replaced `flipCard.innerHTML` with `innerFlipCard.innerHTML` in the `setTimeout()` and moved a few lines and the cards are now flipping on click! Many many thanks for pointing me in the right direction, and I learned something!